# Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

On an Angular app using Typescript I have the following:

```js
  userId?: number;
  token?: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 

    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
      (value: ParamMap) => {
        this.userId = value.has('userId') ? +!value.get('userId') : undefined;
        this.token = value.has('token') ? value.get('token') : undefined;
      }
    );

  }
```

But I get the error when defining `token`:

```
Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

How can I make this work the same was as when defining `userId`?

Answer (score 0):

[`ParamMap.get`](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#get) returns `string | null`. Since your `token` effectively has type `string | undefined`, those are not compatible (undefined and null are different things in JS/TS). Just handle the `null` case with the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) while also getting rid of `has` (it is redundant).

```
this.token = value.get('token') ?? undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of any variable in type script is undefined, you have declared variable as nullable type (? -nullable type). So if there is no value assigned to that will assign null.
so it can not take undefined as you already have declared as null able type.
Change the defined to null as following.
this.userId = value.has('userId') ? +!value.get('userId') : null;
this.token = value.has('token') ? value.get('token') : null;

Check the above code is working or not if not working then check what is type of token variable you declared in ParamMapv) or share where you have assigned token value.